# How to convert PHP $datetime to User Local Timezone

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, timezone

How can I convert a $datetime in PHP (servertime)
to Users local timezone using JS?

```
<span class="datetime"><?php echo $datetime; ?></span>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is value of $datetime.Answer depends on its value.

Comment: $datetime is a MySQL Value e.g. '2012-06-08 18:00:00'

Comment: Yet answer still depends on your server timezone.It is better if you convert it to unix epoch time.

Comment: @McBabba Did you end up solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) or [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```

For more :- [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  Set your initial value to be a unix timestamp:

```
<span class="datetime"><?php echo strtotime($datetime); ?></span>
```

Then use JQuery to replace that timestamp with the datetime in the local timezone:

```
$(function() {
  $(".datetime").each(function(idx) {
     var converted = new Date( parseInt($(this).text()) * 1000 );
     $(this).text( converted.toString("ddd MMM d yyyy H:mm:ss") );
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Better send unix timestamp to the frontend and then convert that into a local date using Javascript.

Comment: What you're suggesting is exactly what the OP is asking in his/her question.

Comment: No, I am suggesting a way of doing it so that it is easy for backend and frontend to do the conversions. Backend does not need to know about the frontend timezone and can always send the unix timestamp which can be easily converted by JS.